# Where can I find piwik JavaScript code

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I have installed piwik in my `Joomla` page using nfrPiwik plugin in order to insert the JavaScript code in order to interact my Joomla page with piwik statistics.

However where can I find this code? Most specifically file which is the file from `Joomla` file which took the JavaScript code from nfrPiwik plugin

Comment: What do you mean when you say `file which is the file from Joomla file`. You may want to check out this plugin too http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/analytics/eorisis-piwik

Answer (score 1):

The files for the plugin are located in the following directory:

```
ROOT/plugins/system/piwik
```

The following file is the one that displays the parameter allowing you to add your tracking code:

```
ROOT/plugins/system/piwik/piwik.xml
```

However it **does not** store your tracking code. This is done in the database

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you mention (nfrPiwik) simply places any code you add to the plugin settings right before the closing `</body>` tag on your website. I'm not sure what code you're looking for, your question is a little unclear, but here's how to add your tracking code:

1. Locate your tracking code. It looks like this, and the Piwik website has a [guide explaining the code](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide):

   ```
   <!-- Piwik -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var _paq = _paq || [];
   (function(){ var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://{$PIWIK_URL}/" : "http://{$PIWIK_URL}/");
   _paq.push(['setSiteId', {$IDSITE}]);
   _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
   _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
   _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
   var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript'; g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js';
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s); })();
   </script>
   <!-- End Piwik Code -->
   ```

   In your tracking code, {$PIWIK_URL} would be replaced by your Piwik URL and {$IDSITE} would be replaced by the idsite of the website you are tracking in Piwik.
2. Locate then nfrPiwik plugin in your plugin manager (**Extensions** - **Plugin Manager**)
3. Paste your tracking code in the text field in the plugin settings, make sure the plugin is enabled, and save.